# Counter not incrementing by 1 - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On button click should be fired a method:

```
fireAction() {
  let counter = 0;
  let total = resp.data.data.offers.length

  switch (operator) {
    case 'minus':
      if (counter > 0) {
        counter--
      }
      break;
    case 'plus':
      if (counter < total) {
        counter++
      }
      break;
  }
}
console.log(counter)
```

However, when i click on the plus button, my `counter` value is set to 1, if i click once more, then value is 1 again, `++` and `--` works differently when using with Vue?

I want on each click to increment the value of counter by 1, e.g.: 1+1=2, then 2+1=3 and so on.

**UPDATE**

It works if i set counter in `data()`:

```
data () {
  return {
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Then use it in my code as `this.counter` - then it works. Could someone explain, why it didn't work in my first code block, when using counter as `let` var, not in `data` method?

Comment: console.log(resp.data.data.offers.length) , what prints that?

Comment: @DamianLattenero it prints 4 integer.

Comment: Every click triggers fireAction() so you set counter to 0 each time. When it is a data element it isn't reset with each click.

Comment: @Andrew1325, lol, thanks. Post an answer. By the way, i still can use `var counter`, but outside of that method. How can i make it global for my current template?

Comment: Ok, posting answer.

Comment: Please just for your personal help try to get atleast the basics of Javascript done before you jump into a framework, it will be less frustrating for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data element exists outside of all methods or functions and is therefore essentially a local 'global' variable. So, as per your question, in fireAction() the variable counter will we initialised (set to 0) inside the method each time it is called, even though you increment it in the method. If defined within 'data' it can be incremented with each call of the method and will persist it's value. You can define a variable outside of your export default and use it in method. eg:

```
<script>
let myVariable = 0

export default {

...

}
```

but using data elements is certainly my preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="app">
  <div>{{ counter }}</div>
  <button v-on:click="increment('plus')">Increment</button>

<button v-on:click="increment('minus')">Decrement</button>
  </div>
</div>


new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
counter: 0
},
methods: {
increment(operator) { 
switch (operator) {
case 'minus':
if (this.counter > 0) {
this.counter--;
}
break;
case 'plus':
this.counter++;
break;
}
}
}
});
```